# QUERY ERROR : ORA-00937: not a single-group group function

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to query the percentage of correct answers in my oracle db

```
SELECT 
    (Count(P2.Id) /(
        SELECT Count(*) FROM POSTS P WHERE P.OwnerUserId = 1
        AND P.PostTypeId = 2)* 100) AS AcceptedPercentage
FROM
    POSTS P1
  INNER JOIN
    POSTS P2 ON P1.AcceptedAnswerId = P2.Id
WHERE
    P2.OwnerUserId = 1
  AND
    P2.PostTypeId = 2;
```

But it gives me this error, how can I fix this?

Comment: @Austin thanks, It works ;)

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statement for the table; the `INSERT` statement for some sample data; and the expected output from the query. If we don't know what you are putting into the query and what you expect out then we have to guess.

Comment: @Austin Are you sure that method gives the expected output? [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=561dac600cc0576c383add48f6974ecf) If you are then you should post that as an answer rather than a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can simplify it using a hierarchical query, however, without any sample data or expected output its difficult to confirm what is expected:

```sql
SELECT CASE 
       WHEN num_posts > 0
       THEN num_accepted_answers/num_posts*100
       END
         AS AcceptedPercentage
FROM   (
  SELECT Count(CASE WHEN LEVEL = 2 THEN 1 END)
           AS num_accepted_answers,
         Count(CASE WHEN OwnerUserId = 1 AND PostTypeId = 2 THEN 1 END)
           AS num_posts
  FROM   POSTS
  WHERE  LEVEL <= 2
  START WITH
         OwnerUserId = 1
  AND    PostTypeId  = 2
  CONNECT BY
         PRIOR Id = AcceptedAnswerId
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE posts (id, owneruserid, posttypeid, acceptedanswerid) AS
SELECT 1, 1, 2, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 2, 2, 1    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 1, 2, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 2, 2, 3    FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | ACCEPTEDPERCENTAGE |
> | --- |
> | 100 |

---

For your query, you can move the main aggregation to a sub-query:

```sql
SELECT CASE
       WHEN (SELECT Count(*) FROM POSTS P WHERE P.OwnerUserId = 1 AND P.PostTypeId = 2) > 0
       THEN total
            /(SELECT Count(*) FROM POSTS P WHERE P.OwnerUserId = 1 AND P.PostTypeId = 2)
            * 100
       END
         AS AcceptedPercentage
FROM   (
  SELECT Count(P2.Id) AS total
  FROM   POSTS P1
         INNER JOIN POSTS P2
         ON P1.AcceptedAnswerId = P2.Id
  WHERE  P2.OwnerUserId = 1
  AND    P2.PostTypeId = 2
);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=2f8d021499c031ff3d7a740a1c5e4055)*

Comment: It gives me : "ORA-01476: divisor is equal to zero"

Comment: @Loki00 Then you have no rows where `OwnerUserId = 1` and `PostTypeId = 2`. Your query will give exactly the same output as the sub-query in the `SELECT` clause will be zero in that case.

Comment: @Loki00 Updated so that you will not get that error.

Comment: It works too :)